# Do I need license to do electrical work in any residential home?

Tags: wiring

I have 4 years apprenticeship, work on my own for 7 years in Africa, and Europe. I have also attended Montgomery college, so I have a total of 32 years in the electrical field. Do I need license before do work any residential homes?

Comment: We don't know where you are now. Africa? Europe? North America? Antarctica?

Comment: Your foreign experience makes things worse.  You must un-learn stuff to comply with local electrical codes.

Comment: Total of 32 years in the electrical field.... Have you been doing things correctly in those 32 years?!

Answer (score 4):

The general answer in most parts of the US is **YES**. The exceptions, *generally*, are:

- Work on your own home
- Limited "handyman" work - e.g., replacing receptacles or light fixtures, but not replacing breaker panels (with the line somewhere in between)

However, the specifics vary tremendously around the country (and even more around the world). Some places require a license to do just about anything. Others are far more flexible.

The requirements to get a license also vary quite a bit. Typically some *combination* of experience (which you have) and knowledge test (of code & best practices).